# Dropbox is not up when I login remotely via ssh

Tags: command-line, dropbox

I have a computer with Ubuntu12.04 and Dropbox. When I login it remotely via ssh, I find that Dropbox's daemon won't be called up. How to solve this problem, please?

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure you have installed the dropbox cli.

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
wget -O ~/bin/dropbox.py "https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py"
chmod +x ~/bin/dropbox.py
```

Now you can at least start the dropbox daemon from an ssh login using:
`dropbox start -i &`

This line can be added to your `.bash_profile` to always start the daemon when logging in via ssh.  The command will confirm that Dropbox is already running if it is in fact already running.

Dropbox CLI documentation can be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/9192

Headless install instructions here are also helpful
https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux